# Find the plane which touches the cone $x^2+2y^2-3z^2+2yz-5zx+3xy=0$ along the generator whose direction ratios are $1,1,1.$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, surfaces

Find the plane which touches the cone $x^2+2y^2-3z^2+2yz-5zx+3xy=0$ along the generator whose direction ratios are $1,1,1.$

---

Let the plane touches the cone at $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$.
We know that the equation of the tangent plane to the cone $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2fyz+2gzx+2hxy=0$ at the point $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ is 
$x(a\alpha+h\beta+g\gamma)+y(h\alpha+b\beta+f\gamma)+z(g\alpha+f\beta+c\gamma)=0$
The equation of the cone is $x^2+2y^2-3z^2+2yz-5zx+3xy=0$.Here $a=1,b=2,c=-3,f=1,g=-\frac{5}{2},h=\frac{3}{2}.$
The equation of the tangent plane is $x(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\beta-\frac{5}{2}\gamma)+y(\frac{3}{2}\alpha+2\beta+\gamma)+z(-\frac{5}{2}\alpha+\beta-3\gamma)=0$
The given plane is parallel to the generator whose direction ratios are $1,1,1$ or whose direction cosines are $\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$
 
So $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\beta-\frac{5}{2}\gamma)+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(\frac{3}{2}\alpha+2\beta+\gamma)+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(-\frac{5}{2}\alpha+\beta-3\gamma)=0$
$\frac{9\beta}{2}-\frac{9\gamma}{2}=0$
$\beta=\gamma$
I am stuck here.Please help me.

Comment: Generators pass through the origin, so you can take $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(1,1,1)$.

Comment: I also tried this way by taking $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(1,1,1)$ and using the equation $x(a\alpha+h\beta+g\gamma)+y(h\alpha+b\beta+f\gamma)+z(g\alpha+f\beta+c\gamma)=0$ and i got $0.x+\frac{9}{2}y-\frac{9}{2}z=0$ but the answer given in my book is $\frac{x}{2}=\frac{y}{-3}=\frac{z}{4};\frac{x}{-11}=\frac{y}{2}=\frac{z}{7}$.I do not understood why.Please help.@Aretino

Comment: The correct answer for the tangent plane is $y=z$, as you found. Are you sure of the answer in your book?